# get_term and get_term_by return null or false, even though term exists

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, actions, terms

I am trying to use the action hooks `delete_term` and `delete_$taxonomy`, among other hooks that delete a term, but they are presenting the same issue.

For example, `1234` is an existing term in the `favorite` custom taxonomy:

```
add_action( 'delete_favorite', function( $term, $tt_id ) {

    $get_term1 = get_term( $term, 'favorite' );
    $get_term2 = get_term( 1234, 'favorite' );

    $get_term_by1 = get_term_by( 'id', $term, 'favorite' );
    $get_term_by2 = get_term_by( 'id', 1234, 'favorite' );
    $get_term_by3 = get_term_by( 'name', 'term-name', 'favorite' );

    $output = 'get_term1: ' . $get_term1 . ' get_term2: ' . $get_term2 . 
        ' get_term_by1: ' . $get_term_by1 . ' get_term_by2: ' . $get_term_by2 . 
        ' get_term_by3: ' . $get_term_by3;

    ob_start();
    var_dump( $output );
    $contents = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    error_log( $contents );

}, 10, 2 );
```

They all return nothing. So, how can I get the term inside these types of functions?

The functions get_term and `get_term_by` work everywhere else but inside these hooks. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

To use `get_term_by` we need the `term` object before it gets deleted. Therefore, we should use the action hook `delete_term_taxonomy` that runs before the term is deleted.

Now, we can go ahead and perform some tasks such as deleting all the `postmeta` related to the `term` being deleted.

The code is:

```
add_action( 'delete_term_taxonomy', function($tt_id) {

    $taxonomy = 'category';    
    $term = get_term_by('term_taxonomy_id', $tt_id, $taxonomy); 
    $user_name = $term->name;
    $meta_key = "_category_relation_added_" . $user_name;
    delete_post_meta_by_key( $meta_key );

}, 9, 1);
```